# MYSQL polygons that contains a polygon

Tags: mysql, database, polygon, spatial

I have a table for segments storages on table as polygons.
Then I want to get all segments that are touched by another polygon for example a square, or a circle.
On image :    http://img.acianetmedia.com/GJ3

I represent small gray boxes as segments and big_BOX .
With this query:

```
SELECT id, position, ASTEXT( value ) 
FROM segment
WHERE MBRCONTAINS( GEOMFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON(( 20.617202597319 -103.40838420263,20.617202597319 -103.3795955521,20.590250599403 -103.3795955521,20.590250599403 -103.40838420263,20.617202597319 -103.40838420263))' ) , value )
```

I got 4 segments that are 100% inside big_BOX, 
but how to get ALL segments that are touched by big_BOX ?

result has to be 16 segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple solution:**
Instead of `MBRContains`, you should use `MBRIntersects` which will return any results that either fully or partially cross space with your big box.

**A caution and full solution:**
Dependent on your data, and the rest of your solution (especially on how big box is formed), it may be possible that you return more than 16 segments due the number of decimal places your coordinates use.  Whilst this is however quite unlikely and would only ever be possible under extreme circumstances its just a possibility to consider.

At 7 decimal places, you're at 1.1cm accuracy (at the equator).  If your big box looked to exactly line up with a 4x4 segment set, it is possible (at an absolute maximum degree) that you actually get a result set of 36 (6x6) due to the coordinates overlapping into the next segment on all sides by even the most minute measurement.  Any multiple of 4 between 16 and 36 inclusive could be possible.

Again, this is largely unlikely, but if you wanted to always ensure a result set of 16 you could use a combination of methods such as `Area(Intersection(@geom1, @geom2))` to calculate the intersection geography between your big box and Intersecting segments, order on that column descending and take the first 16 results.

Whilst this would guarantee the most appropriate 16 segments, it will add additional overhead to all queries just to cater for the most extreme scenarios.

The choice is yours.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Gracias Jon! Really appreciate your advice.